# GoogleMap não redenriza o mapa em aplicação Ionic3 nas plataformas Android e iOS

Tags: android, ios, ionic3, google-maps-api-3

Desenvolvi uma aplicação Ionic 3 e implementei a API do GoogleMaps, quando executo o comando ionic Cordova run browser o mapa funciona perfeitamente, porém quando vou realizar o teste no Android ou no IOs o mapa não aparece, mostra somente a tela com o logotipo da Google no canto inferior. Já segui o manual no site do Ionic Framework, porém a falha continua ocorrendo. Segue abaixo o código do método que forma o mapa.

```
carregarMapa() {
    let element: HTMLElement = document.getElementById('map_canvas');
    let map: GoogleMap = this.googleMaps.create(element);

    Environment.setEnv({
      'API_KEY_FOR_BROWSER_RELEASE': CONF_API.apiKeyGoogle,
      'API_KEY_FOR_BROWSER_DEBUG': CONF_API.apiKeyGoogle
    });

    map.one(GoogleMapsEvent.MAP_READY).then(()=>{
      console.log('Map is ready!');

      let posicao: LatLng = new LatLng(this.posicao.lat, this.posicao.lng);

      let posicaoCam:  CameraPosition<LatLng> = {
        target: posicao,
        zoom: 15,
        tilt: 30
      }

      map.moveCamera(posicaoCam);

      //inserir um marcador
      let marcadorConfig: MarkerOptions = {
        position: posicao,
        title: 'Cliente'
      }
      map.addMarker(marcadorConfig).then((marcacao:Marker) =>{
        marcacao.showInfoWindow();
      });
    })
  }
```

Na plataforma da GoogleAPIs a Chave esta sem nenhuma restrição, as APIs estão ativas. Estou precisando de apoio para fazer funcionar no Android e no iOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver removendo o plugin(`ionic cordova plugin remove cordova-plugin-googlemaps`) e reinstalando novamente.